# How to install office 365 in linux centos 6

Tags: linux, centos-6

i have lots of work in office 365 but recently our company install openoffice which is very difficult doing work, so we want office 365 in linux centos 6, 
kindly suggest me how to install office 365 in linux centos 6

Answer (score 1):

You can't really run it natively (naturally), and its [garbage rated on wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26323). So you're out of luck - You might be able to run the [webapp](https://office.live.com/start/default.aspx) as a reasonable alternative I guess.

Comment: Agreed, Either change OS or try use the webapps.